# Symfony 2.0: Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration::getFilterSchemaAssetsExpression()

Tags: symfony

I am trying to use Doctrine 2 Migrations in my Symfony project.

for that, I first put

```
[doctrine-migrations]
   git=http://github.com/doctrine/migrations.git

[DoctrineMigrationsBundle]
   git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle.git
   target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMigrationsBundle
   version=origin/2.0
```

in th deps file.

Then I am updating vendors with:

```
php bin/vendors install
```

And try to use

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

But I am getting there a fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration::getFilterSchemaAssetsExpression() in /home/milos/workspace/Symfony/vendor/doctrine-migrations/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php on line 85

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration::getFilterSchemaAssetsExpression() in /home/milos/workspace/Symfony/vendor/doctrine-migrations/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php on line 85
```

Comment: which version of doctrine-common, doctrine-dbal and doctrine do you have on your deps file?

Comment: doctrine-common : version=2.1.4; doctrine-dbal : version=2.1.7; doctrine : version=2.1.7; Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that doctrine migration is calling a function which only exists in Doctrine 2.2, not Doctrine 2.1. This was just introduced a few days ago in [this commit](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/commit/5dffedde3b33fad793f5bf8a11f738d8aaf6f579)

The problem is that doctrine-migrations does not have any branches or tags, so you cannot ask for an older version which works for you.

It is difficult to upgrade to Doctrine 2.2 if you are using symfony-2.0. So, what I would do is remove the lines introduced in that commit manually for now and then open a new issue on the [doctrine-migrations github](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations) explaining the situiation and asking for a fix (probably the best idea would be to add a tag for the version which is compatible with Doctrine 2.1)

**EDIT**

This has been fixed now thanks to the issue opened by @Milos! You should not find this problem anymore.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. In fact, I am using Symfony 2.0.17 and I am following a tutorial on how to use symfony because I am a novice. In this tutorial, they are using php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff. How can I remove those lines manually and where ? Thanks.

Comment: They are here: /home/milos/workspace/Symfony/vendor/doctrine-migrations/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php and you can see which lines to remove in the link for the commit

Comment: Even if you are just doing this just to learn about Symfony, please go to the migrations github and open an issue (it is quite easy to do and is a skill you will need in the future), you´ll be doing everyone who may find this problem in the future a favor

Comment: Thank you Carlos, i fixed the issue on my local machine and i will go immediately to open an issue.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I created an issue.